# Template parse error on using ng-template instead of template

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have angular 2 rc.1 application. The problem is I am trying to override the existing pager by nesting a ng-template with the directive kendoPagerTemplate inside the kendo-grid. 
like -

```
 <kendo-grid>
    ...
    <ng-template kendoPagerTemplate>
        <!-- add custom components or reuse existing pager elements --->
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

but i am getting following error - 
[image: error image]

my code is below html  -

```
 <kendo-grid #grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" [pageable]="true" [skip]="skip"  style="cursor:pointer" pageSize="10" >
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of columns" [field]="getColumnField(column)" [title]="getColumnTitle(column)" [width]="getColumnWidth(column)">
                <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column="column">
                <span  [title]="column.title" (click)="onTemplateSpanClick($event)">{{column.title}} </span>
                </ng-template>


                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                       <span *ngIf="column!== 'Status'" [title]="column.title">         
                         <span [title]="column.title">
                   <!-- {{dataItem[column]}} -->
                   <span [innerHTML]="dataItem[column]"></span> 
                   </span>
                    </span>

                 </ng-template>

            </kendo-grid-column>

        </kendo-grid>
```

Is there any way to change the existing the kendoGrid footer template , like make it clickable and change color?

Comment: Did you import Angular's `CommonModule` in your module?

Comment: @ConnorsFan - no i have not imported angular's CommonModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Angular's changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc1-2017-02-24), the `ng-template` directive was introduced in version 4.0.0-rc.1. Therefore, it was not available in Angular 2 rc.1, the version that you are using. The equivalent in that version was the `template` directive.

If the Kendo component requires `ng-template`, it may not be compatible with Angular 2. You can find more details about these compatibility issues on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/469).

Comment: fan is there any other way to manipulate the pager with template directive for angular 2 rc.1

Comment: I am not familiar with the Kendo components. The only options I see for paging are the ones given in [this documentation page](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/paging/). If you cannot upgrade to Angular 4 or 5, you can take a look at [the Angular-Kendo compatibility packages](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/469).